# Magento Custom Api v2 resource path not callable when compilation mode enabled

Tags: php, api, magento

The custom api function call fails with error message "Resource path not callable" after compilation is enabled. The custom api works as expected when compilation is not enabled.

**Question**

*Is it possible to configure a custom Magento api so that it can be called when both compilation is disabled AND enabled in versions 1.5 and above?*

2 workarounds will succeed with compilation enabled :

**Workaround #1**:

Rename the compiled file from (lowercase the v in V2):

```
/includes/src/MyApi_Test_Model_Objectmodel_Api_V2.php
```

to

```
/includes/src/MyApi_Test_Model_Objectmodel_Api_v2.php
```

**Note**: this must be executed after compilation is enabled, and done each time compilation occurs

**Workaround #2**:

Rename the original **V**2.php file to **v**2.php in :

/app/code/local/MyApi/Test/Model/Objectmodel/Api/V2.php

**Note**: this will fix the api function to succeed 100% of the time when compilation is enabled, but removing the V2.php will break the v2 usage when compilation is disabled. Having BOTH a V2.php and a v2.php will fix both scenarios, but it appears that the 2 files cannot be bundled together for deployment (in addition to not being DRY).

**EDIT**
Adding more details.

---

I've traced the execution and issue using this very helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520970/magento-api-v2-php-error/8526835#8526835), and have come to the following conclusions (all code is taken from version 1.9.1.0 CE):

The V2.php is searched for in the includes/src directory as /includes/src/MyApi_Test_Model_Objectmodel_Api_**v**2.php.

The "call" function in /var/www/html/includes/src/Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract.php contains the following line :

```
$modelName = $this->_prepareResourceModelName((string) $resources->$resourceName->model);
```

and _prepareResourceModelName will append the _resourceSuffix, if it exists, which in this case is '_v2' because it is called in :

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Handler.php 
protected $_resourceSuffix = '_v2';
```

The output becomes :

$resources->$resourceName->model=MyApi_Test_Model_Objectmodel_Api

modelName :                      MyApi_Test_Model_Objectmodel_Api_**v**2

Comment: Good research Joe! This already helped my quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> but removing the V2.php will break the v2 usage when compilation is disabled

The right thing to do here is to fix your extension so it works with the class file named `V2.php`.  Uppercased word segments (i.e. `Uppercase_Word_Segments` are Magento's standard for class names, and using a different convention will likely cause other problems.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm trying to understand if that is possible. Is it a problem with my extension's configuration, or will a V2.php file name ever be searched for in a compiled state as <file prefix>_V2.php?